# MySQL "wait_timeout" not being honored for long query?

Tags: php, mysql, timeout, mariadb

I'm trying to test the `wait_timeout` MySQL setting which seems to be ignored.

**PHP script:**

```
<?php
function microtime_float()
{
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
    return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
}

$sql = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','mysql');
$query = "SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name='wait_timeout';";
$result = $sql->query($query) or die($query.'<br />'.$sql->error);
$row = $result->fetch_object();
echo "wait_timeout = " . $row->Value . "<br/>\n";

$time_start = microtime_float();
$query = "SELECT SLEEP(2) FROM mysql.user;";
$sql->query($query) or die($query.'<br />'.$sql->error);
$time_end = microtime_float();
$time = $time_end - $time_start;
echo "Query completed in $time seconds<br/>\n";
echo "You got the page";
```

**Script output:**

```
wait_timeout = 2
Query completed in 8.0005459785461 seconds
You got the page
```

**My configuration**

```
mariadb-server-5.3.5
php5.3.6
```

**What do I need to do in order to force MySQL to time out queries after a certain amount of time?**

Comment: Both `wait_timeout` and `interactive_timeout` is the time of inactivity before the connection is dropped. So, the connection must be idle (not running a query) before it will be dropped. MySQL SLEEP() does not count, since you're running a query. You'll have to manually kill long running queries. You can script this.

Comment: I think you're trying to use wait_timeout incorrectly. wait_timeout and interactive_timeout aren't for query duration if I remember correctly. They're for inactive connections not slow queries or the SLEEP containing query, the connection is still fine and active...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `wait_timeout` and `interactive_timeout` is the time of inactivity before the connection is dropped. So, the connection must be idle (not running a query) before it will be dropped. MySQL `SLEEP()` does not count, since you're running a query.

You'll have to manually kill long running queries (there's no setting to have MySQL do it for you). You can script this. Use `SHOW PROCESSLIST` (or external tools like [Innotop](http://code.google.com/p/innotop/)) and `KILL`.

Comment: Is there any setting that would enable MySQL to stop the execution of queries after a given predefined amount of time?

Comment: No, there is no setting that offers that functionality. As I described in my answer, you can script it using `SHOW PROCESSLIST` and `KILL`. There may be some third party scripts or programs that can do this.

Comment: @user359650, [mk-kill](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-kill.html) is a command-line tool that you can specify criteria for which process to kill (e.g. busy-time). For a complete tool kit that includes mk-kill, see the [Percona Toolkit](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-toolkit/).

Comment: I'm very surprised that `MySQL` doesn't handle the termination of queries based on predefined timeouts natively. `mk-kill` seems indeed like what I need. It's now part of the `percona toolkit` (http://www.percona.com/software/percona-toolkit/)

Comment: Yes, wait_timeout is client inactivity timeout. To my knowlegde, only .NET and Java clients have client-side timeouts, which would have the effect of killing long running query whenever statement takes too long. As mentioned here, scripting "SHOW PROCESSLIST" + "KILL" would work.  If you have interest to use something that does not come from the official MySQL nor from forks, Twitter has the implementation on the server-side timeout  in its GIT branch https://github.com/twitter/mysql/wiki/Statement-Timeout