# kindly explain me about 'interactive_timeout' variable in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, variables, database-administration

If a connection last longer than **'interactive_timeout'** limit value, will that connection get dropped automatically.
which are all connections will it drop. I mean only **Sleep connections** or even **active connections** as well?
Then what about **wait_timeout**  variable ... ?? please explain.

Answer (score 1):

**interactive_timeout** - The number of seconds the server waits for activity on an interactive connection before closing it.

**wait_timeout** - The number of seconds the server waits for activity on a noninteractive connection before closing it. This timeout applies only to TCP/IP and Unix socket file connections, not to connections made using named pipes, or shared memory.
 On thread startup, the session wait_timeout value is initialized from the global wait_timeout value or from the global interactive_timeout value, depending on the type of client (as defined by the CLIENT_INTERACTIVE connect option to mysql_real_connect()).

Sleep connections and waiting connections are dropped.

For differences [refer here.](https://serverfault.com/questions/375136/differnce-between-wait-timeout-and-interactive-timeout)

Comment: Both wait_timeout and interactive_timeout is the time of inactivity before the connection is dropped. So, the connection must be idle (not running a query) before it will be dropped. MySQL SLEEP() does not count, since you're running a query.
Kindly check this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027453/mysql-wait-timeout-not-being-honored-for-long-query?rq=1).